# How to get Spring to use older version of Guava for specific Dependency, but newer version for "main" project

Tags: spring, dependencies, spring-cloud

I have a dependency in my SpringBoot project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-cluster-zookeeper</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Which requires Guava 16.01

However, my "main" project which I'm including cluster-zookeeper in requires Guava 28.2

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>28.2-jre</version>
</dependency>
```

When I run SpringBoot App, I get error:

```
The following method did not exist:

    com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.sameThreadExecutor()Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/ListeningExecutorService;

The method's class, com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/blah/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/28.2-jre/guava-28.2-jre.jar!/com/google/common/util/concurrent/MoreExecutors.class

It was loaded from the following location:

    file: /blah/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/28.2-jre/guava-28.2-jre.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors
```

It seems like a version conflict issue where Spring tries to get cluster-zookeeper to use newer Guava version, when it require older one. How can I get this to work? I.e use 16.01 Guava for ONLY cluster-zookeeper while keeping 28.2 dependency for my main project?

Comment: Without using things like OSGi that isn't possible, maybe it is time to upgrade that old `spring-cloud-cluster-zookeeper` dependency. 1.0.2 is pretty old, the current version is 2.2.3.

Comment: Looking at the maven page: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-cluster-zookeeper. There doesn't seem to be a newer version.

Comment: I guess it is now named Spring Cloud Zookeeper (which ahs that version). See https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-zookeeper#learn

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll try it, I looked up cloud-cluster because that's what the documentation explicitly told me to add: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#_spring_cloud_cluster

Comment: You still need the specific Zookeeper one as well else it only has an API without a concrete implementation.